# The norm of operator matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be the bounded linear operator on $H$, for $T\in B(H)$, if $T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & B \\
    A & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right)$ on $H=M\oplus M^{\bot}$, then how to compute the norm of $T$? Or,  is there any relationship between $||T||$ and $||A||, ||B||$?

what about $T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
  \end{array}\right)$?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case,
$$
\left\|T\begin{bmatrix}h\\ k\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}Bk\\ Ah\end{bmatrix}\right\|.
$$
As we are free to choose $h$ and $k$, $\|T\|=\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}$.

In the general case, I don't think you can say anything.